# How to Fetch a Website After User Login in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

So i am trying to fetch a div from my university campus system website to show in my React Native App but whatever i try i can't able to do it.

Lets say my campus system's login page in the link of `campus.com/login` . The user has to login with their credentials to get to the main page of the system. Then user has to click a button to go `campus.com/program`. When the user in the `campus.com/program` i need to fetch a div from this page. I can't directly go to `campus.com/program` because it is automatically redirects to login page.

Here are what i tried so far:

1- I tried using `react-native-inappbrowser-reborn` i couldn't found any method to track where the users in the browser.

2- I tried `react-native-webview` with the following code:

```
const jsCode = "window.postMessage(document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML)";
<WebView
               javaScriptEnabled={true}
               injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
               source={{uri: 'https://campus.com/login'}}
               onMessage={event =>
                 console.log(event)
               }
             />
```

This doesn't work either. Nothing returns with the injected javascript.

3- I try to use the `onnavigationstatechange` with WebView but it doesn't work because login and program page is in the same domain.

Is there any method to use for this situation? Do anyone can help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase of anyone get the same issue as me you have to use `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage()` instead of `window.postMessage()`
 and get the message using onMessage prop in the webview.
`